# Filter headers in requests to API Management

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I am deploying an infrastructure in Azure in which I have an instance of API Management.

The problem is that I have to get a statistic from time to time of the requests that arrive at the API, grouping the requests by a specific request header.

I have tried to do it from the resource metrics section and also from application insights, but I can't find the solution.

In my case the header is called "Client"
[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: can you paste your error message here if you are getting any?

Comment: I haven't had any error messages. I just haven't found the right set of filters or metrics within APIM resource management or app insights

Comment: Hi @Jsanchez, Create a custom telemetry processor in your application. It will extract the "Client" header from incoming requests and include it as a custom property in the telemetry data sent to Application Insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add header `Client` in **API Diagnostics Logs** settings as "Headers to log":

[image: Shows how to configure HTTP headers to be logged in Azure API Management with Application Insights]

then header values will be logged in `customDimensions` of `requests` table as `Request-Client` and/or `Response-Client`